# Python run multiple programs in parallel

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Say I have thousands of sensor readings that get added to a queue like Redis or Apache Kafka, and foreach sensor_id to get its own worker that runs calculations on the historic readings. Each sensor_id would be published to a new topic then start streaming the readings.

Each worker would start off by reading from a database to instantiate some of its variable thresholds. The code is identical for EACH worker aside from its sensor_id and variable thresholds retrieved using the sensor_id as the lookup key. Once a sensor_id is added to the queue, it is assigned a worker that runs forever.

Would it be more efficient to do:

1. multiprocessing.Pool to launch thousands of workers that run indefinitely?
2. Or "python script.py param1 param2 &" thousands of times and just changing the params to instantiate? (I would generate a bash script programmatically to include all this logic fyi)

I want all the workers to run in parallel as fast as possible, these are CPU bound tasks, not I/O bound. Which is the best way to launch all the workers?

**Clarification**: Sensor readings will be generated every second per sensor_id so for 3 thousand sensors, 3 thousand events are generated a second, and 3 thousand topics inside the queue. Payload example is JSON {sensor_id: "hash", temperature: 85, rpm: 1200, ...}. My ideal setup was each worker maintaining the last 200 readings or so in memory to run calculations. The alternative being a one central queue where cycled workers would have to first make a db connection to read the 200 readings for the sensor_id it popped off the queue, but this takes time.

Comment: IMHO it would depend on far too many things to even begin to guess... how many sensor ids, how many readings per sensor, how many bytes/kB a reading is, whether the readings are all coming from a single source, how long the calculations take, how fast your network is, how many CPU cores you have, whether there's any disk i/o...

Comment: Just so I understand: You're talking about creating a process pool whose size is in the thousands. And you're saying that the sensors generate values that get added to a queue that presumably your worker functions running in the process pool read in a loop to process. How frequently does a sensor reading occur or, in other words, how many of these thousands of processes are likely to be getting readings concurrently? If the sensors are sending readings concurrently you need a lot of processors! Otherwise, there is a technique for one process to be polling multiple queues.

Comment: "Would it be faster to" is almost always answered by yourself by testing both methods with real data.  And read about the GIL.

Comment: @Booboo yes I was wondering if it was possible running this architecture one thread per sensor to maintain state, but I am limited by number of cores, I've added a clarification for my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that `Redis` lists are more reliable than Publish/Subscribe, which is more suitable when a single message needs to be consumed by multiple consumers. Your application would also be greatly simplified if all the sensors wrote to the same list and then you could have a processing pool of identical workers reading from that list in a loop. The message would naturally identify which sensor was involved and when a worker read a message for a new sensor id that it has seen before, it would have to do a "first time" initialization for that sensor by reading from the database the pertinent information and saving it in a dictionary keyed by the sensor id. Ultimately, this dictionary could end up having 3,000 entries. **This leads to the conclusion that the pool should be initialized once with a dictionary of all 3,000 entries that all workers can access before they even start reading messages.**

The following code can be used, however, if for whatever reason all 3,000 sensors must be writing to 3,000 different `Redis` lists (if you *are* using `Redis` lists to begin with). The idea would then be to find a way to somehow read "simultaneously" from 3,000 lists retrieving the messages as they become available and writing them to a single queue that the workers can be reading from and thus simplifying the worker logic. This code is based on **12.13. Polling Multiple Thread Queues** in *Python Cookbook 3rd Edition* by David Beazley and Brian K. Jones available [here](https://github.com/lpvcpp/learn_python/blob/master/D.%20Beazley%2C%20B.K.%20Jones%20-%20Python%20Cookbook%2C%203rd%20Edition.%202013.pdf). This has been adapted to poll 3,000 `Redis` lists and to send the items read to a single `multiprocessing.Queue` instance. This code also includes a processing pool of `producer` workers emulating the creation of sensor readings that are added to one of 3,000 lists, which you would not have in your actual code here. But the 3,000 `PollableList` instances would have to be accessible to whatever the code is that is responsible for getting the sensor readings. We also have here only a single `Process` reading from the queue of messages, which are objects, and printing them, so as to keep the printing "orderly." In reality, you would have a pool of processes, as I have mentioned.

Unfortunately, the technique described in the Cookbook seems to have a limitation with regards to how large the list passed to `select` can be and so being forced to limit the list size to 500 to be on the safe side, that meant I had to break up the 3,000 `Redis` lists into 6 groups of 500 lists.

```py
import redis
import socket
import os
import json
import select
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from functools import partial

class PollableList():
    r = redis.Redis()

    def __init__(self, idx):
        self.idx = idx
        self.list_name = f'sensor_{idx}'
        # Create a pair of connected sockets
        if os.name == 'posix':
            self._putsocket, self._getsocket = socket.socketpair()
        else:
            # Compatibility on non-POSIX systems
            server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            server.bind(('127.0.0.1', 0))
            server.listen(1)
            self._putsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self._putsocket.connect(server.getsockname())
            self._getsocket, _ = server.accept()
            server.close()

    def fileno(self):
        return self._getsocket.fileno()

    def put(self, item):
        PollableList.r.rpush(self.list_name, json.dumps(item))
        self._putsocket.send(b'x')

    def get(self):
        self._getsocket.recv(1)
        return json.loads(PollableList.r.lpop(self.list_name).decode())

def producer(lists):
    """ emulate the 3000 sensors """
    # Feed data to the lists (we won't run indefinitely)
    for _ in range(3):
        for lst in lists:
            lst.put({'id': lst.idx, 'value': lst.idx * 100 + 1})

def consumer(q, list_names):
    '''
    Consumer that reads data on multiple lists simultaneously
    '''
    while True:
        can_read, _, _ = select.select(list_names, [], [])
        for r in can_read:
            item = r.get()
            q.put(item)

# in actual use case, there would be a pool of workers:
def worker(q):
    message_number = 0
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        message_number += 1
        print(message_number, item)


def main():
    lists = [PollableList(i) for i in range(0, 3000)]
    # select cannot handle all 3000 sockets at once:
    lists1 = lists[0:500]
    lists2 = lists[500:1000]
    lists3 = lists[1000:1500]
    lists4 = lists[1500:2000]
    lists5 = lists[2000:2500]
    lists6 = lists[2500:3000]

    p0 = Process(target=producer, args=(lists,))
    p0.daemon = True
    p0.start()

    q = Queue()
    thread_pool = ThreadPool(6)
    thread_pool.map_async(partial(consumer, q), [lists1, lists2, lists3, lists4, lists5, lists6])

    # This would in reality be a process pool of workers reading from q:
    p1 = Process(target=worker, args=(q,))
    p1.daemon = True
    p1.start()

    # wait for all 9000 messages to be displayed by worker:
    input('Hit enter to terminate...\n')

# required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```